# Can somebody help me get started with postScript?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have downloaded ghostScript and gsview, and I'm wondering how do I write a program in notepad and interpret it using the command line? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure it's in the `$PATH`, and run the console program `gswin32c yourfile.ps`.

Answer (score 5):

The PostScript Language Reference Manual (the Red Book) is essential for writing PostScript programs, you can download it from the Adobe web site (the location keeps changing so I'm not going to post a URL).

In addition the Blue Book (PostScript Language Tutorial and cookbook) and possibly the Green Book (PostScript Language Program Design) might well be useful.

If you want to deal with creating fonts then you will need the Black and White book for PostScript type 1 fonts (and Adobe tech note 5015), the TrueType specification and the type42 font specification (Adobe tech note 5012) for TrueType fonts and for CIDFonts tech notes 5014 and 5092. For CFF fonts you would need tech note 5176.

Finally I very much recommend John Deubert's excellent series of journals on the Acumen Training website www.acumentraining.com.

You need not interpret files from the command line, Ghostscript has an interactive mode. If you run GS you will see the prompt 'GS>' you can type PostScript at the prompt and it will be interpreted. Alternatively, as luser droog says simply pass the filename as an argument to the Ghostscript binary executable (the name of the Ghostscript executable varies across platforms)